# Can we use Stardog to query .ttl files?

Tags: stardog

I'm asking myself a question : I have a .ttl file stored somewhere on the internet (let's say http://www.example/org/myFile) and I want to query it.

Can I use Stardog to query it ? Something like (in node.js)

```
const stardog = new Stardog({
           endpoint: 'http://www.example.org'
});
```

and query it with a SPARQL command line ?

**I'm asking myself this question** because I think the .ttl file need to be stored in a Stardog instance. (and then, http://www.example.org is supposed to be a Stardog instance !)

Thanks,

Clément

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is true that you cannot query a Turtle file. You need to first load it into a Stardog database. See the [Known Issues](http://www.stardog.com/docs/#_known_issues_2) in Stardog documentation:

> Queries with FROM NAMED with a named graph that is not in Stardog will not cause Stardog to download the data from an arbitrary HTTP URL and include it in the query.

If you have data stored in another SPARQL endpoint you can query it using SPARQL's [federated query](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-federated-query/) functionality (`SERVICE` keyword) without loading the data into Stardog.